# Automatically opening marker info pane on google map

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I've created a custom map with most things I want on it (custom icon and custom info bubble), however I can't find a solution to automatically open the markers info window on load, I've done alot of searching but can't seem to find anything the code I have so far is as follows, any help would be much appreciated:

```
    function initialize() {

      var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(54.325109,-2.742226);

      var myOptions = {
        zoom: 15,
        center: myLatlng,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
      }

      var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);

      var countries = [
        {
          title:'Remedy', 
          lat:54.3210, 
          lon:-2.7438,
          content:"<h2>Remedy</h2><p>address, <br />location, <br />postcode</p> <p><b>T:</b> 07595 153 835 <br /><b>E:</b> <a href='mailto:email'>email</a></p>"
        }
      ];

      for (var i = 0; i < countries.length; i++) { 
          var c = countries[i]; 
          c.marker = new google.maps.Marker({
              position: new google.maps.LatLng(c.lat, c.lon), 
              map: map,
              icon: '/wp-content/themes/remedy/display_images/google_map_icon.png',
              title: c.title});
          c.infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({content: c.content}); 
          google.maps.event.addListener(c.marker, 'click', makeCallback(c)); 
      } 

      function makeCallback(country) { 
          return function () { 
              country.infowindow.open(map, country.marker); 
          }; 
      }

      infowindow.open(map, marker);

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmm, **inforwindow** does not refer to anything in your code, which is why it is not working.

Since you have one country in the list as of now you can do a quick test and intialize the **infowindow** variable with an actual info window, or better yet also since you have 1 item in the list, just define c to be outside the loop so you can access it and then open the popup passing it the map and the marker, something like this (assuming c has been defined outside the loop)

```
c.infowindow.open(map, c.marker);
```

Comment: wow thanks, nice easy fix for once! Thanks so much you've save me from a headache ;)

Answer (score 2):

Maybe it's not working because you just created the instance of the Map and didn't wait for the complete load of the map to open the InfoWindow.

Try something like this:

```
google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(map, 'tilesloaded', function(event) {
    infowindow.open(map, marker);
});
```

According to the reference:
http://code.google.com/intl/en/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/reference.html#Map

tilesloaded - This event is fired when the visible tiles have finished loading.

Answer (score 0):

```
var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
    content: "Test Route",
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(38.8709866, -77.208055),
});
infowindow.open(map);
```